# How to store specific data into list with class

Tags: c#, .net, list

i want ask about storing data into list but not all data like this,
class Category :

```
public class CategoryEnt
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }
    public bool IsTopCat { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrending { get; set; }
    public int SequenceID { get; set; }
    public string Filtering { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

i just want add to list CategoryID, CategoryName, ImageUrl

```
 while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CategoryEnt category = new CategoryEnt();
                    category.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CategoryID"]);
                    category.CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString();
                    category.ImageURL = reader["ImageURL"].ToString();

                    list.Add(category);
                }
```

the right now, rest of data include but with default/null value, i dont want rest of data include to list. how to store just specific data to list? any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that Directly, but indirectly you can achieve the same by using the following code:

```
List<CategoryEnt> CategoryEntList = new List<CategoryEnt>();       
while (reader.Read())
{
    CategoryEntList.Add(new CategoryEnt(){ 
    CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CategoryID"]),
    CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString(),
    ImageURL = reader["ImageURL"].ToString(),
    });
}
var requiredValues = CategoryEntList.Select(x => new 
                                    { CategoryID = x.CategoryID, 
                                      CategoryName = x.CategoryName, 
                                      ImageURL = x.ImageURL 
                                    }).ToList();
```

Now `requiredValues` is a List that will contains only those value that you ware specified in the `Select` You can proceed with that;

Comment: yes, like that, but how to return to list, because my method is public list<> , so must return list variable

Answer (score 0):

Try a class with just the information you require. Something like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create your original class using

```
public class CategoryEnt
{
    public Category CategoryPrimaryDetails { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }
    public bool IsTopCat { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrending { get; set; }
    public int SequenceID { get; set; }
    public string Filtering { get; set; }
}
```

And your original code becomes:

```
List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Category category = new Category() {
      CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CategoryID"]);
      CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString();
      ImageURL = reader["ImageURL"].ToString()
    }

    list.Add(category);
    CategoryEnt detailedCategory = new CategoryEnt() {CategoryPrimaryDetails = category};
 }
```